# Importing Excel with apex

Tags: salesforce, apex

I'm having a problem with apex: I created a dialog that allows me to load a CSV file. However, when I loaded it, it returned the following error message:

> 09:17:41:021 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [19]|e|"common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string"|0x72d1bdb2

In the CSV file, there are symbols like "-" and "_". I suspect this would be the reason why it was failed to load.

This is my code:

```
public class ImportExcel {  
    public String fileName {get; set;}
    public Blob contentFile {get; set;}
    public String[] csvFileLines {get; set;}
    public List<String> acclist {get; set;}
    public String[] data {get; set;}

    public ImportExcel() {
        csvFileLines = new String[]{};
        acclist = New List<String>();
    }

    public void readFile() {
        try {
            fileName = contentFile.toString();
            system.debug(fileName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL,'Please upload a valid CSV document');
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
            return;
        }

        csvFileLines=fileName.split('\n');
        for (Integer i = 1; i < csvFileLines.size(); i++) {
            data = csvFileLines[i].split(',');
            acclist.add(csvFileLines[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I helped to improve the English and formatting of this post. Please format your code properly in the next time. Thanks!

Comment: I did not understand your answer

Comment: No, I did not answer your question. I made changes in your question so that it looks better.

Comment: but I have seen your modification

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the binary data in your file that your code cannot handle.

The `contentFile` is a `Blob` and when you use `contentFile.toString()` the functions look for compatible UTF-8 strings. Your data might include binary data that `toString()` is unable to work with them.

If you need the binary data stored as string anyways you can use `EncodingUtil.base64Encode(contentFile)`.

More info [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm) and [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008mCnIAI).